# Hibernate entity inheritance. Single table lazy loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I need to implement entity property lazy loading. I came with single table inheritance approach.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Getter
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;
}

@Entity
@Getter
public class VerbosePerson extends Person {
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;
}

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
public interface VerbosePersonRepository extends JpaRepository<VerbosePerson, Long> {}
```

Unfortunately, this only works with a discriminator column. Actually, I don't need to distinguish these two entities. All that requires is to exclude `lastName` column from the `Person` fetching and to load it only when `VerbosePerson` is being requested.

One solution is to declare `@MappedSuperClass` that should have two inherited entities (`Person` and `VerbosePerson`). But in this case, `Person` won't be a supertype for `VerbosePerson` which is not convenient.

Is there any way to use single table strategy inheritance without discriminators?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need lazy querying and not the inheritance. You should take a look at FetchType annotations

https://thorben-janssen.com/entity-mappings-introduction-jpa-fetchtypes/

Be warned though.. these are primarily used to manage lazy loading for Lists (things that can be easily proxied). Lazily associating a single item (i.e. a @ManyToOne or a simple string, etc.) usually requires some careful object proxying under the covers to ensure it works the way you think it should in your persistence framework. Generally I didn't use it much but I think I did at one point or another to lazily load a class that had variables mapped to a row of a hibernate object that I lazily loaded..

Check out:

[https://thorben-janssen.com/lazy-load-non-relational-attributes/#:~:text=The%20JPA%20specification%20defines%20the,value%20must%20be%20eagerly%20fetched](https://thorben-janssen.com/lazy-load-non-relational-attributes/#:%7E:text=The%20JPA%20specification%20defines%20the,value%20must%20be%20eagerly%20fetched).

Pay special attention to the parts:

practices, that means that depending on your JPA implementation, annotating an attribute with @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) isn’t enough.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading for fields requires bytecode enhancement. Then you can use `@Basic(fetch = LAZY)` and the field will be lazy loaded on first access. Also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement